# Brute-force crack time for 56 bits and 64 bits (DES)

Tags: security, aes, brute-force, des

I've been looking online for a simple way to calculate the average time it would take a computer to crack a 56 bit and 64-bit key using a brute-force but I can't find any simple explanation for it or a formula to calculate it.

Is there a way I can calculate how long it would take to brute-force 56-bits and how would I calculate how much the time would increase by if i increase the key by 1 bit?

Comment: If you increase the key size by one bit, you need twice as much time, as the time is in `O(2^n)` for `n` bits. Otherwise your question is vague: what algorithm are we talking about? (DES?) Can we assume we can use the Birthday attack?

Comment: @ThomWiggers Yes I'm talking about a DES algorithm. I forgot to mention it..

Comment: Then it still is too vague (and off topic for this site!): what kind of computer are we talking about, do we have FPGAs, …. As an aside, this is a trick question: DES keys are 56 bits with 8 bits of padding. So 64 bit DES keys only have 56 bits of key material.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on an algorithm implementation (raw or heavily optimized) and hardware which this implementation will be run on (CPU (multicore?), GPU or FPGA, ASIC). 
However, you can check some benchmarks of oclhashcat (GPU) and john the ripper (CPU), and then divide keyspace size 2^56 or 2^64 by number of combinations these crackers do per second. Then you can easily convert it to minutes, hours and so on...